# StyleTypedProperty Attribute not working in WinRT designer for custom control

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have created my own custom control in WinRT, which has own template for it. My custom control contains many inner custom elements(Small Controls) which are also having own templates.

Then i tried to provided the designer edit facility in Visual Studio for all that templates by StyleTypedProperty attribute and it results fail to me. In designer,EditTemplate working fine for my Control but EditAdditionalTemplates does not contain the templates of inner elements of my control.

NOTE: Same working fine in WPF designer.

Any one faced this kind of issue or please provide some suggestions?

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "PopupStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(Popup))]
public class MyControl : Control
{
}
```